# Appending to tibble in FOR loop R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to create a list of all possible IP addresses in the UK, so I can plot them on a map for a data science project I am working on.

I have tried to simplify the code as much as possible, basically I have a created a blank tibble to use in the for loop, but it does not appear to get any data appended to it.

Guessing I have done the append part of the FOR LOOP incorrectly.

```
#install libraries
library(iptools)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

#creating a list of ip ranges for processing
ip_ranges <- list("2.96.0.0/13", "2.120.0.0/13", "2.216.0.0/13")

#converting list into dataframe
ip_ranges_to_process <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, ip_ranges)
colnames(ip_ranges_to_process) <- c("ip.ranges")

#creating a blank tibble for use in for loop
UK_ip_addresses_df <- tibble(
  var_name_1 = character()
)

new_df <- tibble(
  var_name_1 = character()
)

#for loop to generate all possible ip addresses in ranges
for(i in 1:nrow(ip_ranges_to_process)){
  ip_numbers <- range_generate(ip_ranges_to_process$ip.ranges[i])
  new_df <- ip_numbers %>% 
    map_df(as_tibble)
  UK_ip_addresses_df[i,] <- new_df
}
```

Any suggestions would be welcome. Sorry I am pretty new to programming.

Comment: You're overwriting `new_df` in every iteration of your `for` loop.  You *could* write `new_df <- new_df %>% bind_rows(ip_numbers %>%  map_df(as_tibble))` instead, but this would be hideously inefficient, especially if you have a large number if IP address to process.  Better would be something like `new_df <- lapply(ip_ranges_to_process, function(ip) as_tibble(range_generate(ip))) %>% bind_rows()`, which takes the binding outside of the "loop" and is therefore much more efficient.

Comment: @Limey great thanks for your help. I will give the modified loop a go this afternoon.

Comment: @Limey hello, just tried it and it worked. Thanks, your a legend. Hope you have a nice day. Rob